# Click Python - How to manage options in one function when that function has too much options

Tags: python, click

I'm working with Click-7.1.2 in order to import data to MongoDB by Pymongo. Because I'm new to Click, so that I put all options in one function `main()` .After that, I will get values of those options received over the command-line and pass to other functions.

```
def import_data(processed_data):
    # do something with the processed_data


def filter_time(processed_data, timeline):
    # filter time and return data


@click.command()
@click.option('--file', 'filepath', prompt="File pạth please", help='Choose your file path.', type=click.Path(exists=True, path_type=type(json)))
@click.option('--from', 'timeline', help='Choose your datetime.', type=click.DateTime(formats=["%d/%m/%Y"]))
@click.option('--silent', 'silent_mode', help='Disable log.', is_flag=True)
def main(filepath, timeline, silent_mode):
    if silent_mode:
        logger.disabled = True
    result = []
    logger.info("Read file: %s", filepath.decode('utf-8'))
    with open(filepath) as f:
        # return processed_data

    if not timeline:
        import_data(processed_data)
    else:
        import_data(filter_time(processed_data, timeline))
```

As you can see, the `main()` function has only three options now. What can I do when it becomes bigger and has more options or arguments? Of course, not every option is to add a decorator to the beginning of the function. I don't think that it is efficient to split an option with each function, which can lead to difficulty calling variables once they are `local` variables. Has anyone ever met this situation? Please help me! I want to write code that is scalable and clean.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you considered maybe using a switch statement? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python

Comment: I dont think it is useful for my case

Comment: In particular, I was looking at https://stackoverflow.com/a/30881320/2675981, but if that doesn't work, then it doesn't work.